# Accessing JSON data on JQuery Mobile pageshow() event

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, initialization, undefined

I am working on a single page JQuery Mobile site. JQuery initialization is initially set to false while JSON data is loaded and the DOM is manipulated client side. After the content is loaded and DOM manipulated, JQuery Mobile is initialized.

Once initialized, I am planning to use Ben Alman's replaceText plugin to drop JSON into some placeholders that are within the outputted HTML, so a placeholder like "XXFIRST_NAMEXX" becomes "John Smith".

I haven't gotten to the replacement part b/c I am unable to access the JSON data from within JQuery Mobile's pageshow() event, even though that the last event to fire in the sequence of events loading the page.

Below is a simplified and commented version of my code.
I am using JQuery 1.7.1 and JQuery Mobile 1.1.0
What am I missing here?
Thanks!

```
// jQuery Mobile initialization
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    //prevent JQM from initializing until after content has been loaded in .getJSON callback;
    $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
});

$( document ).bind( "pageshow", function( event, data ){
    console.log('pageshow fires'); //fires 4th

    //DROP-INS
    //need to replace text within manipulated and initialized html
    var resplaceScope, strDisplayName, strSchoolName, strOfferTitle; 
    replaceScope = $('body *');
    //collect variables from json data
    strOfferTitle = data.content.offer_vars.offer_title; //ERROR Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offer_vars' of undefined 
    replaceScope.replaceText( /XXOFFER_TITLEXX/gi, strOfferTitle );
});

$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log('document.ready fires'); //fires 1st

    $.getJSON('io_content.json', function(data) {
        console.log('getJSON fires'); //fires 2st
        getContent(data);
        // ... once code is manipulated by getContent, Jquery is ready to initialize
        $.mobile.initializePage();
    });

    function getContent(data){
        console.log('getContent fires'); //fires 3rd
        // ... code to manipulate content client side before jquery mobile initializes
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on, but is it possible that you're expecting the "data" parameter passed into the "pageshow" callback to be the same as the "data" variable in the "getJSON" callback? They are different objects that just happened to both be named "data". The one from "pageShow" just has a "prevPage" property that contains a reference to the DOM element that represents the page that was just navigated away from. The one in the getJSON callback has the actual data you got from the data source; once the callback finishes executing, it's gone.

If it's not possible to do all of this initialization in the JSON callback, then you might try using jQuery's data() function to store the bits of the JSON that you need on some DOM element in the page. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that does help! I didn't think about data being two different things - one thing to getJSON and another to pageShow. Once I declared my dropin variables globally, and defined them within getContent(), pageShow had what it needed to act on. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I had difficulty doing this with `data()`, or even `jqmData()` which is what should be used instead of `data()`. From the docs:

> When working with jQuery Mobile, jqmData and jqmRemoveData should be
>   used in place of jQuery core's data and removeData methods (note that
>   this includes $.fn.data, $.fn.removeData, and the $.data,
>   $.removeData, and $.hasData utilities), as they automatically
>   incorporate getting and setting of namespaced data attributes (even if
>   no namespace is currently in use).

To overcome this I stored the data in LocalStorage in the getJSON callback and then could access it from pageShow

Comment: jqmData() ... interesting, I didn't know that. Somehow I missed blowing my hand off on a previous project!

Comment: :) it may be a relatively new addition, I've not been using the framework long. But I came up against this exact issue just the other day...